# Modify object position with AngularJS works just one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I got an array of object call $scope.postsATraiter, and I got a function who give a random x y value for each post.

```
 $scope.posAleatoire = function () {
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.postsATraiter.length; i++) {
            var l = parseInt(Math.random() * (w - 200));
            var t = parseInt(Math.random() * (h - 200));
            $('#target'+i).css({
                'left': l + 'px',
                'top': t + 'px',
                'height' : '200px'
            })
        }
    }
```

This works fine but only if I use it in this function :

```
Posts.query({}, function() {
    $scope.postsATraiter = $scope.posts;
    $scope.posAleatoire();
});
```

This function is call  before every one, and she get all the post in my database and store it into $scope.postsATraiter, if I use posAleatoire in another place in my code it does nothing, why ?

I post the HTML if it can help.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts track by post._id">
     <div id="target{{$index}}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `$scope.posAleatoire()` is dependent on `$scope.postsATraiter`, so that's why  when you call `$scope.posAleatoire()` outside that function were you are assigning values to  `$scope.postsATraiter`, does not work.

Before calling `$scope.posAleatoire()`, you have to varify that `$scope.postsATraiter` has some values.

Comment: this is strange because I use some other functions with ´$scope.postsATraiter´ and I dont need to verify values and the other functions works well, I don't know but maybe the bug comming from the modification of the css